# How to pass POST parameters using PhpStorm REST CLIENT

Tags: phpstorm, rest-client

POST parameters are passed in request body

In which format do I need to pass them in PhpStorm REST CLIENT?

I tried

param=value
param:value

Nothing works. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Headers section of the Request tab (within the REST Client window), be sure to add a `Content-Type` header and set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do form submit in html this actually set the request header `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` in case of the file upload then it will set the request body exactly same as the GET url parameters for example `email=test@test.com&password=123123`.

So this should work with you: 
[image]